# multiprocessing.Process calls main function from process creation line to end of line repetitively?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have two files. One is to create and return a process. Another is to create many multiple processes asynchronously.

The problem I have is, why line `print("all process created")` (line 13) in the second file has executed 3 times?

## process1.py

```
import time
import multiprocessing 

def wait(s):
    print(f"Waiting for {s} seconds...")
    time.sleep(s)
    print(f"Done Waiting for {s} seconds...")

def create_process(sec):
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait, args=(sec, ))
    p1.start()
    return p1
```

## main_file.py

```
from process1 import create_process
import time

procs = []

def many_process():
    global procs
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for i in range(1,4):
            print(f"creating process to sleep {i}")
            p = create_process(i)
            procs += [p]

    print("all process created")

many_process()
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

## output:

```
creating process to sleep 1
creating process to sleep 2
creating process to sleep 3
all process created
all process created
Waiting for 1 seconds...
all process created
Waiting for 3 seconds...
all process created
Waiting for 2 seconds...
Done Waiting for 1 seconds...
Done Waiting for 2 seconds...
Done Waiting for 3 seconds...
```

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? You need a `if __name__ == "__main__":` to keep the reimported script from running the main code on every subprocess.

Comment: @tdelaney: There's such a guard in the `many_process()` function in the `main_file.py` script.

Comment: @martineau - but that guard doesn't protect the print that concerns the poster. I was primarily asking about which platform is being used and noting why the guard is important. Questioner has so far failed to answer my simple question so I just moved on.

Comment: @tdelaney: I see…and In that case I suspect the problem is simply that the `print("all process created")` isn't placed where it will be protected by the `if __name__ == "__main__":` that's already there. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @martineau - Yes, and the guard really should be placed at the module level. Having the code call `many_process` and do other processing on import is risking more bugs in the future.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, I'm using Windows. You are right. if the print is under if statement it prints once.
Thanks for reply:)

Comment: @tdelaney how do I stop it without if statement? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing can fork or spawn processes. Since Windows doesn't support fork, spawn is its only option. When spawning, a new python instance is created and must be initialized to both load the worker code and build the environment for it to execute. That include importing modules, including the script that started it all.

For this to be successful, the modules must be import safe. That is, mere import doesn't run more code than you want it to. In your case, the extra code was reasonably benign. Since you used an `if` to keep `many_process` from creating processes on import, all that happened is that the print that should also have been in the `if` spit out incorrect information.

But really, the `if` should be higher up the code than that. The create process function should not have been run at all.

main_file.py

```
from process1 import create_process
import time

def many_process():
    global procs
    for i in range(1,4):
        print(f"creating process to sleep {i}")
        p = create_process(i)
        procs += [p]
    print("all process created")

if __name__=="__main__":
    # emulating windows on other platforms for test, remove in real code
    import multiprocessing
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

    procs = []
    many_process()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```